# "Binning" records by attributes: how to structure the ActiveRecord call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a Report:

```
create_table "reports", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date "date"
  t.bigint "technology_id", null: false
  t.bigint "user_id", null: false
  t.bigint "contract_id", null: false
  t.integer "distributed"
  t.integer "checked"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer "people"
  t.integer "reportable_id"
  t.string "reportable_type"
  t.integer "impact", default: 0
  t.bigint "plan_id"
  t.integer "year"
  t.integer "month"
end
```

I'm trying to create a collection that looks like this:

```rb
{ year: { month: [:id, :id, :id] } }
```

I've been playing around with this:

```rb
Report.select(:id, :year, :month).group(:year, :month, :id).order(year: :desc, month: :asc)
```

I actually don't want `:id` to be in the `.group()` method (because I want to group by `:year` and then by `:month`) but I get the oh-so-common error:

```rb
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "reports.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Any advice on creating this collection without doing an N+1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the SQL can't go further than selecting the rows and assigning an order. What comes then is to handle it for the proper format:

```
Report
  .select(:year, :month, :id)
  .order(year: :desc, month: :asc)
  .group_by(&:year)
  .transform_values do |reports|
    reports.group_by(&:month).transform_values do |month_reports|
      month_reports.map(&:id)
    end
  end
```

Comment: The beauty of this! `.transform_values` for the win!!! Thank you so much!